# How can I make a tab image larger?

Tags: android

I got this image in a tab but it's too small. how can I scale it up or make it fill the tab

```
final TabHost tabHost = getTabHost(); //edit: added this line
tabHost.addTab(tabHost.newTabSpec("tab3").setIndicator("Discussion",
      getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.forum))
                        .setContent(new Intent(this, MyActivity.class)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a `LinearLayout` as a child of the `TabHost` and add your image to that `LinearLayout`

Comment: how do you add a linearlayout to tabhost? what about adding the tab how does the image relate to the tab?

Comment: Sorry, I meant a FrameLayout.  You can add a LinearLayout to the FrameLayout child and make that bigger.

Answer (score 0):

You won't be able to with the method you're using. The drawable is mean't to be a small icon. If you want something custom, you'll have to use `setIndicator(View)` instead. I'd image you'd create an `ImageView` set to use the drawable you want and pass that in. If you wanted the text "Discussion" to still be there, you'd had to create a layout with an `ImageView` and `TextView` and use that.